# How can you trigger view (partials) changes in JS based on data flow?

Tags: javascript, mustache, templating

I have the classic problem everyone has: I did something, change the interface. Now, I have the option of murdering the code with stuff like this, **which I currently have to do:**

```
ajax_call.done(function() {
    //Look at the current view, see what data came, do a check like:
    if(data_that_came_back.component_activated == true) {
        //Update the view with a new view that I have to write custom templates and so on. }
   )
});
```

This is dirty. It forces me to keep thinking about classes when I should only be thinking of data and a controller should decide what view to change based on what data I get back. I know this is what React was built for, but is there no cleaner solution, a library that I can use for this specific thing?

I'm basically trying to go from this:

[image]

to this (when the user clicks "Activate"), when the AJAX call is processed:

[image]

and finally, to this, once the AJAX call is done and successful:

[image]

I can't even think what hell I'd have to go through if I had to handle more cases (such as, what if a weird error happens, what if the call is not successful, what if resources are not available, etc.).

Comment: So what is the specific question? UI's can be complex

Comment: @charlietfl Sorry. Even if non-specific: what is an elegant way to do it? I understand that "elegant" is subjective, but I'm sure everyone understands that nested ifs with `remove/addClass` isn't exactly pretty.

Comment: Still pretty broad. Only suggestion I have is use helper functions